# Probability for event to occur exactly $k$ times

Tags: probability, random-variables

> The probability to send a computer-word correctly is $0.8$. A computer sends $1000$ words. Let $X$ to be the random variable = "exactly $k$ words sent wrong". What is the distribution of $X$?

Is it:

$$P(X=k) = 0.2\cdot {1000 \choose k} + 0.8\cdot(1000-k)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $X$ is a binomially distributed random variable, specifically we can write: $X\sim \mathrm{B}(1000,0.2)$, and thus we can write:

$$P(X=k) = \binom{1000}{k}(0.2)^{k}(0.8)^{1000-k}$$

Which we can see as there are $\binom{1000}{k}$ combinations of $k$ words which are wrong, and the probability of getting exactly $k$ words wrong is: $(0.2)^{k}(0.8)^{1000-k}$.